# How can I reduce squeaks in wood floors when no felt paper was installed between floor and plywood?

Tags: wood, floor, squeak

I've purchased a home where the previous owner installed 3/4" wide plank pine over a 5/8" plywood subfloor.  The plywood is glued to a concrete slab but there is no felt paper between the 2 woods.  Yes - it squeaks!  They wanted the character but we'd like a little less squeak.

Any ideas on what I could do to reduce (not eliminate) the squeak?

Comment: 3/4" WIDE? or 3/4" thick with some other width?

Answer (score 3):

Since it is on a concrete slab, I don't think there is much you can do except tear it out and start over.

Answer (score 0):

There are several projects for just such a problem. The general ideal is that fill the void under the wood floor that is allowing the flex. I have no experience with any of them, but here is one such product http://www.woodfloorinjectionkit.com/ - you inject an epoxy through the wood into the void.